# GPU support for geostatistics in R

Tags: r

I am using R for geostatistical analysis and spatiotemporal variogram calculations on a server. Although it has very high specifications but using variogramST takes a very long time (12 hours so far and still running) because I'm working on a relatively big data set. I have found some R packages that use CUDA. Is there any GPU support for geostatistics packages like gstat and spacetime?

Answer (score 4):

No. Two students of mine have been working on implementing conditional simulation on a GPU; this work is found [here](http://gpusim.r-forge.r-project.org/). I'll give it a thought on how variogramST can be made faster. Have you thought about giving it a smaller data set, to begin with?

Comment: The data I'm using is a set of measurements in a certain region over 7 days, that's why it's a big data set. And I'm trying to study the behavior over the 7 days so I cannot reduce the size. I noticed it's very slow due to the "tunit" parameter in variogramST. When I set it to "days" it takes around 15 hours to finish. "hours" takes around 4-5 hours, and "mins" takes a few minutes